# vuforia/unity app, crash with heavy fbx file

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I create unity and vuforia app and export it for android application and app work very well with light fbx object but when use heavy fbx object ( 3d scan from face), app is crashed after splash page in android.
I try to reduce file size of object but object quality is very bad , how can I import fbx heavy file object (124 MB) in unity and vuforia AR application

Comment: Do you download the model or is it built with the app? You should run the app with adb or xcode so you can see the debug and the crash report.

Comment: To import heavy fbx files you need a good device with good RAM memory to avoid out of memory crash. If not... reduce mesh is the only way. Magic not exist.

Comment: my model create and export from 3d scanner , and my system have a good RAM , and I can import model and build android app successfully but in android device, app is crashed after splash page

Comment: So most likely your mesh is cut in chunks that are bigger than 64k vertices. If you provide a model into editor that is 100k verts, Unity will cut it into two meshes. At runtime, it throws exception. Maybe you could start looking into this.